# Mongodb php datetime filter not working properly

Tags: php, mongodb

I use mongo db with php I need a last 1 hour data. I implement as like bellow.

```
{
  "_id":{"$oid":"5ff42b30be00ec1eaf261db1"},
  "logtype":"syslog",
  "message":"Jan  4 06:51:56 4S-096 kernel: [70745743.387001] CPU7: Package temperature above threshold, cpu clock throttled (total events = 2955852254)",
  "node_id":875,
  "app_id":0,
  "send_to_slack":1,
  "created_date":{"$date":"2021-01-05T09:02:39.593Z"}
}
```

PHP CODE

```
$client = mongodb_connect();
$db     = $client->$db_name;
$col    = $db->selectCollection($collection_name);
$client->selectDatabase($db_name);

$criteria = array(
        "created_date" => [$gte=> new  \MongoDB\BSON\UTCDateTime(strtotime("-1 hour") * 1000)],
        "logtype" => $logType,
        "message" => trim($logdata),
        "node_id" => $node_id,
    );

   
$count = $col->count($criteria);
```

I need a count result. thanks in advance

Comment: Try `"created_date" => [ '$gte' => new MongoDB\BSON\UTCDateTime(strtotime("-1 hour") * 1000)],`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I am not so familiar with PHP, but I think `$client->$db_name` is equal to `$client->selectDatabase($db_name)`

However `->` does not work with variables, so `$client->$db_name` may fail.

Try this one:

```
$client = mongodb_connect();
$db     = $client->selectDatabase($db_name);
$col    = $db->selectCollection($collection_name);

$criteria = array(
        "created_date" => [ '$gte' => new MongoDB\BSON\UTCDateTime(strtotime("-1 hour") * 1000)],
        "logtype" => $logType,
        "message" => trim($logdata),
        "node_id" => $node_id,
    );

$count = $col->count($criteria);
```

I never used `strtotime`, maybe you have to skip  `* 1000`